# Form Hidden by jQuery Code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm not very good at jQuery. I have to show a form in the code below, but it seems jquery (or Javascript) keeps the code hidden.

The sample output is in`http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/products/business-cards/`. If you click the "CONTINUE" button in the page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact Page
 *
 * Description: Twenty Twelve loves the no-sidebar look as much as
 * you do. Use this page template to remove the sidebar from any page.
 *
 * Tip: to remove the sidebar from all posts and pages simply remove
 * any active widgets from the Main Sidebar area, and the sidebar will
 * disappear everywhere.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <script type="text/javascript">
var x1 = 5;
var x2 = 10;
var value = x1 * x2;
var list_value = 1;
var size, fold, back, front, qlnt, qlt, tprice;

</script>

<div id="jdModal">
<div id="jdModalContent" style="padding:10px;background:#fff;">
    <form id="product_form" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fold" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="back" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="front" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="qlnt" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="qlt" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tprice" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="Business Card" />
        <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
        <div><label>Business Name*</label><input type="text" name="businessName" value="" /></div>
        <div><label>Your Name*</label><input type="text" name="yourName" value="" /></div>
        <div><label>Email*</label><input type="text" name="yourEmail" value="" /></div>
        <div><label>Phone*</label><input type="text" name="yourPhone" value="" /></div>
        <div><label>Delivery Region*</label><input type="text" name="deliveryRegion" value="Christchurch" /></div>
        <div><label>Employees</label><input type="text" name="employees" value="1-5 staff members in my business" /></div>
        <div><label>&nbsp;</label><p class="note">If required please upload your files here (2 MB max).</p></div>
        <div style="position:relative"><label>Upload file</label><input type="hidden" value="" id="jd_upload_uri_1" name="jd_upload_uri_1" /><input type="text" class="jd_upload_filename" name="jd_upload_file_1" readonly="readonly" /><input type="button" class="jd_upload" id="jd_upfile_1"value="Browse ..." />
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative"><label>Upload file</label><input type="hidden" value="" id="jd_upload_uri_2" name="jd_upload_uri_2" /><input type="text" class="jd_upload_filename" name="jd_upload_file_2" readonly="readonly" /><input type="button" class="jd_upload" id="jd_upfile_2" value="Browse ..." />
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative"><label>Upload file</label><input type="hidden" value="" id="jd_upload_uri_3" name="jd_upload_uri_3" /><input type="text" class="jd_upload_filename" name="jd_upload_file_3" readonly="readonly" /><input type="button" class="jd_upload" id="jd_upfile_3" value="Browse ..." />
        </div>
        <div><label>Message</label><textarea name="msg"></textarea></div>
        <div><label>I'm also interested in</label><p><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Business Cards" /><span>Business Cards</span><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Flyer" /><span>Flyer</span></p></div>
        <div style="margin-bottom:15px"><label>&nbsp;</label><p><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Booklets" /><span>Booklets</span><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Postcards" /><span>Postcards</span></p></div>
        <div><label>&nbsp;</label><p class="note">To help us fight spam, please type the characters you see below.</p></div>
        <div class="captcha_fix"><label>&nbsp;</label><p style="text-align:right"><input type="submit" value=" " name="productOrderForm" class="submit-product" /><input type="text" name="jd_captcha" class="jd_captcha" value="" maxlength="6" /><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php?captcha" class="jd_captcha_img" /></p></div><div id="jd_msg_box"><p class="text"></p></div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </form>
</div>
    </div>
    <iframe name="formFrame" id="formFrame" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php?load"></iframe>
<div id="file-upload-elem">
<form id="upload_form_1" class="uploader-box uploader-box-1" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="upload_file_1" class="inp-file" id="upload_file_1" /></form>
<form id="upload_form_2" class="uploader-box uploader-box-2" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="upload_file_2" class="inp-file" id="upload_file_2" /></form>
<form id="upload_form_3" class="uploader-box uploader-box-3" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="upload_file_3" class="inp-file" id="upload_file_3" /></form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fileUploadElem = jQuery("#file-upload-elem").html();
jQuery("#file-upload-elem").remove();
var insertUpload, jd_error, jd_success, upload_error, jd_show_msg, invalid_captcha;
var isCustomQuote = false;
jQuery(function() {
console.log("Test");
if(jQuery("#customs").length > 0 || jQuery("#frprice").length > 0) {
    jQuery("body").append(fileUploadElem);
    var calculate = function() {
        if(jQuery("#frprice").length > 0) {
            size =  (jQuery("#foldet").val()).split(":");
            fold =  (jQuery("#fold").val()).split(":");  
            back =  (jQuery("#black").val()).split(":");  
            front =  (jQuery("#front").val()).split(":");  
            qlnt =  jQuery("#qlnt").val();  
            qlt =  jQuery("#qlt").val(); 
            var str = parseInt(size[0])+parseInt(fold[0])+parseInt(back[0])+parseInt(front[0])+parseInt(qlnt)+parseInt(qlt);
            tprice = parseInt(str);
            jQuery("h3#price span").text(tprice);
        }
    };

    var jd_timer;
    var upload_on_progress = 0;

    jd_error = function(errCode) {
        clearTimeout(jd_timer);
        if(errCode == 0) {
            jd_show_msg("Please fill all required fields (*)");
        }
        if(errCode == 1) {
            jd_show_msg("Invalid Email Address.");
        }
        if(errCode == 2) {
            //jd_show_msg("Invalid Email Address.");
            alert("Form sending failed. Please try again later");
        }
        if(errCode == 3) {
            alert("Invalid Action. Please Contact Administrator.");
        }
    };

    invalid_captcha = function(x) {
        if(x == 0) {
            alert("Please Enter Verification Code.");
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Verification Code. Try Again.");
            jQuery(".jd_captcha_img").each(function() {
                jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src')+'&x='+Math.random());
            });
        }

        jQuery(".jd_captcha").val("");
    };

    jd_success = function() {
        setTimeout(function() { window.location = document.URL+"?thank-you"; },2000);
    };

    upload_error = function(err,uid) {
        upload_on_progress--;
        jQuery("input[name=jd_upload_file_"+uid+"]").val("");
        alert(err);
    };

    insertUpload = function(data,file) {
        upload_on_progress--;
        var tmpData = data.split(':');
        if(tmpData.length == 3) {
            var tmpCounter = 0;
                      jQuery("input[name=jd_upload_file_"+tmpData[2]+"]").val(file);
            var updateInput = jQuery("#jd_upload_uri_"+tmpData[2]);
            var updateData = tmpData[0] + ":" + tmpData[1];
            updateInput.val(updateData);
        } else {
            alert("Uploading File Error. Please Try Again Later");
        }

    };

    jd_show_msg = function(err) {
        var myBox = jQuery("#jd_msg_box");
        myBox.children(".text").text(err);
        timer = setTimeout(function() { myBox.hide(); },3000);
        myBox.show();
    };

    jQuery("select").change(calculate);

    jQuery("#price").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });
    jQuery(".jd_upload:eq(0), .jd_upload_filename:eq(0)").css("opacity",1);
    jQuery(".file_input_hidden:eq(0)").show();
    var jdModal = jQuery('#jdModal').html();
    jQuery('#jdModal').remove();
    var uploaderBox = jQuery(".uploader-box");
    jQuery(".inp-file").click(function(e) {
        if(upload_on_progress > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Prevented");
        }
    });
    var cboxTopCache = 0;
    var cboxLeftCache = 0;
    var fixFileWin = function() {
        var fixLeft = 585;
        var cboxOffset = jQuery("#colorbox").offset();
        cboxLeftCache = cboxOffset.left;
        cboxTopCache = jQuery("#jd_upfile_1").offset().top;
        jQuery(".uploader-box-1").css("top",    (jQuery("#jd_upfile_1").offset().top) + "px");
        jQuery(".uploader-box-2").css("top",(jQuery("#jd_upfile_2").offset().top) + "px");
        jQuery(".uploader-box-3").css("top",(jQuery("#jd_upfile_3").offset().top) + "px");
        uploaderBox.css("left",(cboxLeftCache+fixLeft) + "px");
    };
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        var cboxOffset = jQuery("#colorbox").offset().left;
        var cboxOffset2 = jQuery("#jd_upfile_1").offset().top;
        if(cboxOffset != cboxLeftCache || cboxOffset2 != cboxTopCache) {
            fixFileWin();
        }

    });

    var formOnClick = function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        isCustomQuote = (jQuery(this).attr('id') == 'frprice')?false:true;
            jQuery.colorbox({html:jdModal,opacity:0.8,overlayClose:false,transition:'none', onComplete: function() {

            fixFileWin();
            uploaderBox.show();
            jQuery(".inp-file").change(function() {
                var _this = jQuery(this);
                if(_this.val() != "") {
                    if(upload_on_progress > 0) {
                        alert("Upload is still in progress.     Please wait.");
                    } else {
                            jQuery("input[name=jd_"+_this.attr("id")+"]").val("Uploading File.. Please Wait..");
                        _this.parent().submit();
                        upload_on_progress++;
                    }
                }
            });

            if(!isCustomQuote) {
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=size]").val(size[1]);
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=fold]").val(fold[1]);
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=back]").val(back[1]);
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=front]").val(front[1]);
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=qlnt]").val(qlnt);
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=qlt]").val(qlt);
                jQuery("#product_form input[name=tprice]").val(tprice);
            }

            jQuery("#colorbox #product_form").submit(function(e) {
                var tmp_progress = upload_on_progress;
                if(tmp_progress > 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Upload in progress. Please wait.");
                }
            });

        }, onClosed: function() {
            uploaderBox.hide(); 
        }});
    };
    jQuery("#frprice").submit(formOnClick);
    jQuery("#customs").click(formOnClick);
    if(!isCustomQuote) {
        calculate();
    }
}

});
</script>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you bit a bit more precise? what is going wrong? what does firebug/other debuggers output? could you put it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You should debug your code, track down the error, isolate it and post only the relevant part of code that's failing. Btw, if you put your jQuery code inside a document ready function you can pass `$` as parameter and use that instead of `jQuery(this), jQuery(that)`.

Comment: I put the site here: 'http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/contact/'

The problem is the <form id="product_form"> and other html mark up is not shown. Im using wordpress custom page template to generate the code. Normally, the code must appear below the HEADING 'Contact Us' but there are jquery code involved that keeps the mark up hidden. So the goal is to show the form markup in the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
jQuery("#file-upload-elem").remove();
```

With

```
jQuery("#file-upload-elem").hide();
```

jQuery.remove(), completely removes the selected element from the DOM

EDIT:
To show the element when you need it use

jQuery.show()

i.e `jQuery("#file-upload-elem").show();`

**http://jsfiddle.net/MJwFj/2/**

**although it looks very rough when .remove() has been commented out the form loads**

Comment: Thank you very much Ciaran. I tried your solution too but it seems not working. Hmm. I really wonder what piece of the code keeps the markup hidden

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle please it might make it slightly easier

Comment: please check http://jsfiddle.net/MJwFj/2/ when jQuery("#file-upload-elem").remove(); is removed the form appears

Comment: Ciaran. Thanks, i really don't know how to display my code in jsfiddle. Only one thing, even i remove the comment tag (//) for the .remove() function, the markup still appears

Comment: you have to hit run, after you alter the JS, also can you post a Screen shot of how your seeing the form on your website as when i load up the form it looks fine

Comment: Here is a screen shot: http://clip2net.com/s/58h4pw

Comment: can you post a screen shot of what your seeing on your site

Answer (score 1):

```
uploaderBox.hide();
```

The code above will hide the following, the **above code** is safe to remove if you don't want this to happen:

```
<form id="upload_form_1" class="uploader-box uploader-box-1" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="upload_file_1" class="inp-file" id="upload_file_1" /></form>
<form id="upload_form_2" class="uploader-box uploader-box-2" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="upload_file_2" class="inp-file" id="upload_file_2" /></form>
<form id="upload_form_3" class="uploader-box uploader-box-3" action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/ecs/formHandler.php" target="formFrame" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="upload_file_3" class="inp-file" id="upload_file_3" /></form>
```

It's not clear exactly which element is being hidden but there is also a timer that triggers after 3 seconds to hide another element. Try removing the following also:

```
timer = setTimeout(function() { myBox.hide(); },3000);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but It still have the same output.

Comment: @Jed specifically what is being hidden?

Comment: @Francis from looking at his code `timer = setTimeout(function() { myBox.hide(); },3000);` looks as if it hides an error box after its displayed and doesn't look like it alter his form

Comment: @Francis. That's the problem,i really don't know. But the whole markup is hidden... You can check 'http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/products/business-cards/' and click the "Continue" button. The form that will popup is exactly what is hidden in my code..

Comment: @Jed can you post the code for which specific element are meant to be shown!! as i still cant clearly understand which element's you want to see

Comment: @Jed that 'hidden' part is `<div id="jdModalContent"...`

Comment: @FrancisKim did you mean say that to me ?? and that loads clearly in my browser when i click on his button so i cant see the issue

Answer (score 1):

The first, you may set the css role display to the element you wanted to as none

```
.form{
    display:none;
}
```

then you just need to show the form with jQuery .show() function on event you wanted to, such button clicked or something else. For example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.classOfButton').on('click',function(){
        $('.form').show();
    );
})
```

**Update**
if you wanted to show the form within the page are loaded, you need to put the javascript in the end of page, or if you use jQuery you just need to use .ready() function and inside of it you show up the form with some delay if necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form').show();
})
```

Comment: Do i need to to click something with these line of codes?

Comment: @Jed yes, it is the button or element with class .classOfButton

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arif. Can you revise the code so that I don't need to click any button or link. Actually the goal is to show the as the page loads... The issue is when the page loads, if the js codes are executed, the markup is hidden.